# Docker - mssql-linux:2017-latest port 1433 allocated

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am attempting to create a Docker container from a SQL Server image using the following Docker command:

```
   docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=p@$$w0rd!" -p 1433:1433 --name sql2 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

However, the running the command tells me that port 1433 is already in use:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external 
connectivity on endpoint sql2 
(6cfcd552054d9e9d62d1e9ec1c11a6c5051e6912cc6658e12b0bc5e992c30cfd): Error 
starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:1433 failed: port is already allocated.
```

There are no other existing containers, and running the `docker container ps -a` command displays the container, but without a specified port.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error message and what can be done to fix it?

(Windows 10 -- Docker for Linux)

Comment: Open a powershell on your machine and try to find out what is running on this port with `netstat -an | Select-String :1443`

Comment: In concert with the advice  @S.Spieker, you could try binding to a different port on the host machine. That is, change the second 1433 in `-p 1433:1433` in your `docker run` command.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have SQL Server installed that is using port 1433. You can

1) Use a different port
2) Shut down SQL Server service (using services.msc)